# How to handle differences of neocortical parcellations between groups

Tags: regression, t-test, modeling, multilevel-analysis, assumptions

In my lab, we are currently looking at how two handedness groups (mixed handed and consistent handed) differ in terms of lGI ([local Gyrification Index](https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/LGI), a cortical folding measure) across 74 different brain regions. We are thinking of different methods of comparing the handedness groups. One idea that was proposed was to calculate mean lGI for each brain region (74 different means) for each group, and then compare across the groups. The proposed idea was to do a paired sample t-test between the handedness groups, the justification being that mean lGI for Region 1 for one hand group is paired to mean lGI for Region 1 for the other hand group.

Two questions:

1. Is it justifiable to use a paired sample t-test in this context (and why or why not)?
2. Can you think of a way to approach this problem without

   a. data reduction,
   b. a multilevel model with 74 level 1 equations, or
   c. 74 different regression equations?

Note that we are also interested in seeing how sex and intracranial volume influence lGI.

Comment: Is there a reason why you've ruled out a-c a-priori?

Comment: Well, I'd rather not do a factor analysis or PCA because there is evidence that the extent of lGI has functional implications in terms of behavior, and even neighboring regions can have disparate functions. I wouldn't feel comfortable boiling all the regions down to a small handful of components. I didn't really want to go the b or c path because looking at 74 different equations can be awfully intractable in terms of presenting the data. I realize my options are somewhat narrow, but I thought someone might be aware of techniques that I'm not.

Comment: A multilevel model wouldn't mean that you have 74 equations, you would have 1 equation w/ a random effect. You *could* get 74 BLUPs, but you don't have to.

Comment: As a caveat, I'm quite new to mixed level modeling, but I was under the impression that I would need different level 2 predictors for each brain region. I guess what's tripping me up a little is there's no nesting as each participant is measured on each region. The way I was visualizing this is testing each random effect of participant in a level 1 equation for each brain region, and comparing between fixed effects of brain region (74 different regions) in the level 2 equation, but perhaps I'm mistaken in how to approach this or my interpretation?